# Program that changes a number from the base n to another base m

Tags: ruby

I was just curious as to how to change a number from number base `m` to another base `n` with a Ruby program, not a gem. Has anyone done this and would like to share their thoughts or ideas? Just thought it would be fun to try out a program like this :)

I've done it for bin to dec, dec to bin, dex to hex, hex to dec, but would want to know how to do it from m to n.

```
def bin2dec(num)
  sum = 0
  i = 0

  while i < num.length
    sum += 2 ** i * num[num.length - i - 1].to_i
    i += 1
  end

  return sum
end

bin = gets.chomp
out = bin2dec(bin)
print out

def dec2bin(dec)
  out = ""
  num = dec

  while num != 0
    out = "#{num % 2}" + out
    num = num / 2
  end
  return out
end

dec = gets.to_i
print dec2bin(dec)
```

Comment: `89.to_s(2) # => 1011001`

Comment: ^ `"1011001".to_i(2) #=> 89`

Comment: _“how to do it from m to n“_ – convert base m to base 10 and then base 10 to base n. You said you already implemented it for base 2 and base 16. Try to make your implementations more alike, until they only differ in `2` and `16`. Then extract the hard-coded base as a variable and you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

These functions are built in.

To convert "EFFE" from base 16 (hex) to base 8 (octal)...

```
"EFFE".to_i(16).to_s(8) 
# => "167776"
```

To put this in a method...

```
def convert_base(string, from_base, to_base)
  string.to_i(from_base).to_s(to_base)
end
```

Comment: I know that but if that function was no available and you have to manually write the program like I did above, how would it be done?

Comment: Ok, see my other answer.

Comment: This only works if the bases are no greater than 36.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, exactly.  If there's a convention as to what characters represent values larger than 35 then the `characters` array could be extended. Alternatively if the base 40 number is represented as an array of decimal integers, like [3, 2, 38, 0] the method could dispose of the characters array.  All depends on how you expect to present a "base 40" number.

Comment: @CarySwoveland oh, wait, you replied to THIS answer.  I dunno, never checked out the limits of the built in converters.  Hope you're safe and well in these extraordinary times!

Comment: `Integer#to_s` and `String#to_i` also only support 2 <= base <= 36.

Comment: Think about it, what would `36.to_s(37)` return? Considering that `35.to_s(36)
 => "z"` and `('z'.ord + 1).chr
 #=> "{"`, perhaps is should return `{`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a method which converts any positive base to any other positive base, start looking at [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits). It takes an argument (10 by default), but nothing stops you from getting a number in base 543.

Comment: I didn't know `digits` could take a radix as an argument. New in Ruby v2.4, so it's been around awhile.

Answer (score 1):

For `11 <= n <= 36`, Ruby has a convention that allows integers to be expressed in base `n` with the 10 digits `0-9` and the first `n-10` characters of the alphabet. It is for that reason that we obtain the following results:

```
1270.to_s(36) #=> "za"
"za".to_i(36) #=> 1270

1270.to_s(37) #=> ArgumentError (invalid radix 37)
"za".to_i(37) #=> ArgumentError (invalid radix 37)
```

Ruby's representation of integers, however, is just a convention.

I will only deal with non-negative integers and will refer to them as "numbers". Negative integers can be negated, converted to a number of a different base and then that number negated.

We could express numbers of any base as arrays of digits, where each digit is expressed as a base 10 integer. For example, we could write:

- `46` in base 10 as `[4, 6]`
- `za` in base 36 as `[36, 10]`
- a two-digit base N number as `[n, m]`, where `n` and `m` are both between `0` and `N-1`.

We can write a method to convert a base 10 number to this array representation:

```
def base10_to_base_n(n10, radix)
  arr = []
  while n10 > 0
    n10, rem = n10.divmod(radix)
    arr << rem
  end
  arr.reverse
end
```

```
base10_to_base_n(123, 10)
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
base10_to_base_n(131, 2)
  #=> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
abase10_to_base_n(1234, 16)
  #=> [4, 13, 2]
base10_to_base_n(9234, 99)
  #=> [93, 27]
```

Note that, in the third example:

```
4*(16**2) + 13*(16**1) + 2*(16**0) #=> 9234
```

Next we create a method that does the reverse: converts a number in a given base, described as an array of digits (the argument `base_n`) to a base 10 number.

```
def base_n_to_base_10(base_n, radix)
  pow = 1
  arr = base_n.reverse
  base_n.reverse.reduce do |n10, digit|
    pow *= radix
    n10 + digit*pow
  end
end
```

```
base_n_to_base_10([1, 2, 3], 10)
  #=> 123
base_n_to_base_10([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 2)
  #=> 131 
base_n_to_base_10([4, 13, 2], 16)
  #=> 1234 
base_n_to_base_10([93, 27], 99)
  #=> 9234
```

As expected, if

```
radix  = 87
n10    = 6257
base87 = base10_to_base_n(n10, radix)
  #=> [71, 80]
```

then:

```
base_n_to_base_10(base10_to_base_n(n10, radix), radix)
  #=> 6257
base10_to_base_n(base_n_to_base_10(base87, radix), radix)
  #=> [71, 80]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `11 <= n <= 36` be  `2 <= n <= 36` ?

Comment: @steenslag, I've reworded my first sentence without changing my intended meaning. Does that address your comment?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it without the built-in methods...

```
def convert_base(string, from_base, to_base)
  characters = (0..9).to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
  string = string.to_s.upcase.gsub(/[^0-9A-Z]/i, '') # remove non alphanumeric
  digits = string.split('')
  decimal_value = digits.inject(0){|sum, digit| (sum * from_base) + characters.find_index(digit) }
  result = []
  while decimal_value > 0
    result << characters[decimal_value % to_base]
    decimal_value = decimal_value / to_base
  end
  result = result.join.reverse
  return result if result.length > 0
  '0'
end

convert_base('effe', 16, 8)
# => "167776"
```

Comment: That didn't work at all...

in `+': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: So you have characters in the string that are not 0 through 9 or A through Z.  You might need to clean up the input string.

Comment: Added a cleanup line to ensure spaces and other non alphanumeric characters are stripped out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day